# Thalys surcharge with "Any Dutch Station" ticket

Tags: trains, netherlands, belgium

I bought a train ticket from London to "Any Dutch Station".  The ticket indicates that I cannot make use of Thalys services.  Is it possible to purchase a surcharge so that I *can* use Thalys (from Brussels to Amsterdam)?  I only find surcharge information related to Interrail/Eurail, not to "Any Dutch Station" tickets.

It's a Eurostar ticket bought through NS Internationaal.

Comment: You will have to buy a Thalys ticket. There are NS / NMBS trains that leave from Brussels and go to Amsterdam that take about 3 hours 15 minutes.

Comment: @nicholaschris I know there are regular intercity trains.  I was wondering if it was possible to buy a Thalys surcharge without buying the full ticket.

Comment: Are you booking a Eurostar+connections ticket, or a Rail+Sail ticket? (Answer will differ)

Comment: @Gagravarr It's Eurostar.  I forgot to state, but isn't that implied by the fact that I mention the train from Brussels to Amsterdam?  Rail+Sail connects to Hoek van Holland so Thalys wouldn't help that much in getting anywhere.

Comment: Eurostar will happily sell you *either* a Eurostar+Thalys ticket, valid on specific trains, or Eurostar to Any Dutch Station ticket valid on one Eurostar and any non-Thalys after that. Your best bet is probably to ring Eurostar and ask what the change fee would be to switch it to a Eurostar+Thalys ticket (all Eurostar tickets are now at least somewhat flexible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can't just buy a surcharge. All seats on Thalys (like Eurostar) are prebooked with no standing room, so just walking up and boarding isn't going to work.
You'll have to ask to get your ticket converted, take another train, or buy a separate Thalys ticket and eat the extra cost (I wouldn't, the time saved isn't worth it).